# Save a autorecovered word document with the original file name

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, file-recovery, autosave

Word auto-recovers documents that were not saved properly. Occasionally, our network reboots computers, if I have left a document open (which I do often) to continue working on it the next day, the file is easily recovered, BUT Word will not let me save the file with the same name. It will not let me delete the original file (while trying to save the auto-recovered file), because the auto-recovered file has the same name - it sees the file as being open. This is really annoying.

**Is there any way to save a autorecovered file with the same name as the original document?** 
Currently if I want to do that, I need to save the autorecovered document with a different name, delete the original, change the name of the autorecovered file.

For example:
mydocument.doc
The computer re-boots, file is closed without saving.
Autorecovered file -> mydocument.doc (version 1) [autorecovered]
I want to save mydocument (version 1) [autorecovered] as mydocument.doc
This is not possible.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2004/01/28/63741.aspx http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=864 change it for youself. Add macros to Normal.dot